# Ripple effect overflowing out of circular button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, material-design

I have issues managing to make my ripple effect not outgrowing its  container. I set up a oveflow:hidden; but it doesnt work, here's my fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/aqbmbrLy/

```
<div class="row clearfix expand-row">
    <a href="#Projets" class="expand-button scrollTo">
        <i class="medium mdi-navigation-expand-more host-expand actionbutton2">ab</i>
    </a>
</div>
```

I'm basically trying to make the ripple effect not outgrowing the black circle on click, but no matter why I try it stills grow to the full .expand-button and not to the .host-expand, which makes it look bad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check this [link](https://jsfiddle.net/aqbmbrLy/) , i have made changes

```
.expand-row .expand-button .host-expand{
    width:100%;
    display:block;
}
```

add the above code.